# display none in native css taking precedence over media specific css

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm new to this so apologize if terminology isn't quite right. I'm building a website that has 4 style sheets: Base (desktop size and to account for older browsers that aren't compatible with media queries), mobile portrait, mobile landscape, tablet. The last 3 are loaded with media queries.

I have certain div containers that display in Base, but are set to "display:none" in the stylesheets for the smaller devices and this works great.

But I have some that are set to "display:none" in the Base that I want to display in the smaller devices, but "display:none" from the Base stylesheet is taking precedence over the css in the stylesheets for the smaller devices.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked for specificity and cascade issues?

Answer (score 0):

So i presume you are referencing your css like this in your html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="other.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="another.css">
```

in base you have:

```
#element {
 display: none;
}
```

and in another.css you have

```
#element {  display block; }
```

if they are referenced like that the css that is in another.css will overwrite what is in base.

you may have

```
body #element {
 display: none;
}
```

in base.css

and having

```
#element {
 display: block
}
```

in another.css wouldn't work due to your selectors being more dominant in base.css.

if all else fails a hacky way is adding !important to the end of the css rule like:

```
#element {
 display: block !important;
}
```

I dont like using !important but its just an idea if you cant get the css selectors correct

this is all guess work without looking at your css and html

Answer (score 0):

stick display:block in your mobile stylesheet or display:block !important if it still refuses.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @TimBish I don't see why this is not an answer